# jquery. changing div width with animation does not works

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Hello everybody i have variable(widthPercent) where i store percent for example: 67.33%

when i trying to change width with jquery animation it does not works :

```
$(this).animate({
        width: widthPercent,
    }, 2500);
});
```

but changing width with css working good:

```
$(this).css('width', widthPercent);
```

does anyone have idea what is my problem?

Comment: can you show us your widthPercent definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you need to quote the widthPercent

this worked for me

```
$(document).ready(
                function(){
                    var widthPercent = "35%";
                    $("#btn").click(
                    function(){

                        $(this).animate({
                            width: widthPercent,
                        }, 2500);
                    });
                }
            );
```

the problem should be in your widthPercent definition.

Comment: maybe you missed the %? or declared int (without quotes) try it by editing your widthPercent to a string with % at the end

Comment: this has a superfluous comma in it

Comment: @Brandt Solovij it doesn't matter

Comment: hah you're right - i've had it be an issue in the past - go figure.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
var widthPercent = "35%";

$(this).animate({
        width: "'"+widthPercent+"'"   // YOU ALSO HAD AN EXTRA COMMA HERE MEANING IT WAS EXPECTING ANOTHER ARGUMENT -- extra quotes may or may not be necessary depending on what your actual variable looks like
    }, 2500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A2bdQ/5/

also be sure to use quotes when using a % sign otherwise it may be treated as an inline mod operation

Comment: then there is something else wrong. Hah - extra comma. more coffee time.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean:

jQuery:

```
$('#foo').click(function(){
    var widthPercent = '66%';
    $(this).animate({
        'width': widthPercent,
    }, 2500);
});
```

CSS:

```
#foo{
   width:300px;
   background:#ff0000;
   height:100px;   
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A2bdQ/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a '%' character to the width value, like this:

```
$(this).css('width', widthPercent + '%')
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gene/n28Vc/) illustrating it.